# hangman picture isn't changing

Tags: java, swing

I'm busy writing an hangman application and I'm currently checking if some of the code works... now i haven't gotten to hiding the word part yet so in the place of that code i used an if statement as supplementary code:

```
 if(original.indexOf(button.getText())!=-1){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your word does contain" + text );
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no" + text );
                 error++;
             }
             }
```

Anyway when I press the buttons that's not in the word it suppose to add to my errors according to

```
error++;
```

and it only finds the first letter in the word. One of my words are Dinosaur when i press D it says "Yes, there is a D" but when I press A it says "No, there is no I" where the clearly is

Can someone please help

here's my full code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;

public final class Hangman extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
String original = readWord();
int error = 0;
String imageName;

JButton btnAddWord = new JButton("Add New Word");
JButton btnRestart = new JButton("Restart");
JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

JLabel word = new JLabel(original);

static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
static JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();

public Hangman(){
    Container content =getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

   if(error >= 0) imageName = "hangman1.jpg";
   if(error >= 1) imageName = "hangman2.jpg";
   if(error >= 2) imageName = "hangman3.jpg";
   if(error == 3) imageName = "hangman4.jpg";
   if(error == 4) imageName = "hangman5.jpg";
   if(error == 5) imageName = "hangman6.jpg";
   if(error == 7) imageName = "hangman7.jpg";
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    if(imageName != null){
        icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
    }
   JLabel image = new JLabel();
   image.setIcon(icon);

   btnAddWord.addActionListener(this);
   btnRestart.addActionListener(this);
   btnHelp.addActionListener(this);
   btnExit.addActionListener(this);

   panel2.add(image);
   panel3.add(word);
   panel4.add(btnAddWord);
   panel4.add(btnRestart);
   panel4.add(btnHelp);
   panel4.add(btnExit);

    for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++){
        String buttonText = new Character(i).toString();
        JButton button = getButton(buttonText);
        panel1.add(button);
    }
}

public JButton getButton(final String text){
   final JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             if(original.indexOf(button.getText())!=-1){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your word does contain " + text );
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no " + text );
                 error++;
             }
             }
             });
             return button;
}
public String readWord(){
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Words.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(line != null){
            String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
            boolean addAll = words.addAll(Arrays.asList(wordsLine));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
        return randomWord;

}catch (Exception e){
    return null;
}
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == btnAddWord){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Words.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

            String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

            pw.println(word);
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ie){
            System.out.println("Error Thrown" + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnRestart){

    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnHelp){
        String message = "The word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters and category of the word."
               + "\nIf the guessing player suggests a letter which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions."
               + "\nIf the suggested letter does not occur in the word, the other player draws one element of the hangman diagram as a tally mark."
               + "\n"
               + "\nThe game is over when:"
               + "\nThe guessing player completes the word, or guesses the whole word correctly"
               + "\nThe other player completes the diagram";
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message, "Help",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == btnExit){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    Hangman frame = new Hangman();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 600);
    frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that your text comparison is case sensitive.

`"Dinosaur".indexOf("A")` is not the same as `"Dinosaur".indexOf("a")`

I'd suggest converting the text to common case when you compare it.

```
original.toLowerCase().indexOf(button.getText().toLowerCase())!=-1
```

Comment: :( Fastest fingers first! I was writing this as my answer when it the dreaded words popped up: `"1 new answer to the question"`:D

Comment: Thanks didn't really think about that

Comment: @Sujay don't you just love that ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Ah well, I'm getting used to it :D :D

Comment: @user1614977 it would be nice of you to accept this as your answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: new to the site, it told me to wait 6 minutes before i can accept... but just checking if what I did was correct you DO press the check mark right?

Comment: @user1614977 Yep, all worked nicely, always check my answers ;)- seriously though, you can wait to see if there are any better answers, but that's up to you.

Comment: well since all my buttons is uppercase I just added toUpperCase() where you added toLowerCase() but if its possible can ask you to help me with the image changing problem?

Comment: @user1614977 changing the lowerCase to upperCase is fine (mine was just a suggestion). If you have another question, best to post again, comments really arn't a great place to provide detailed feedback :P - but yes, I'll try and help if I can

Comment: thanks, an no i know... its currently 3.30 am and i waaay to into the coding to even have thought that it works fine now thanks to you

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're not correctly checking whether the word that you're reading from the file is in the same case as the text in your `JButton`. There're a couple of ways to fix this:

1. As @MadProgrammer suggested. Have a couple of checks to cover both lowercase and uppercase characters.
2. `Standardizing` your `List<String> words` i.e. keep everything in one case when you're reading from the file. That way you don't have to worry much in terms of checking whether its in lowercase or uppercase. So in this case you might want to change: `String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");` to `String[] wordsLine = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");` or `String[] wordsLine = line.toUpperCase().split(" ");` (*depending on which one you're comfortable with*). Then your check with a single `indexOf()` operation looks fine.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Well, I was typing the answer...thought of posting it anyhow! Thanks!! :)