# change images of hangman with error counter

Tags: java, imageicon

I'm currently testing my hangman application and do not yet have the correct code to hide the original word (that's suppose to be guessed) so in stead i'm using an if statement to tell me if the letter is in the word or not

```
if(original.toUpperCase().indexOf(button.getText())!=-1){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your word does contain " + text );
             }
             else{
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no " + text );
                 error++;
             }
             }
             });
```

Now to my understanding if the letter is not in the word the error must be plussed by 1 integer according to

```
error++;
```

Now for my image code I used

```
 imageName = null;
    error =0;
   if(error >= 0) imageName = "hangman1.jpg";
   if(error >= 1) imageName = "hangman2.jpg";
   if(error >= 2) imageName = "hangman3.jpg";
   if(error >= 3) imageName = "hangman4.jpg";
   if(error >= 4) imageName = "hangman5.jpg";
   if(error >= 5) imageName = "hangman6.jpg";
   if(error >= 7) imageName = "hangman7.jpg";
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    if(imageName != null){
        icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
    }
   JLabel image = new JLabel();
   image.setIcon(icon);
```

according to one of the posts this is correct, but when i deliberately choose a wrong letter (for testing purposes) the image remains the same

and image "hangman1.jpg" is a placeholder, (just the structure)

can anyone show me where i went wrong

for full code see
[hangman picture isn't changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151399/hangman-picture-isnt-changing)

Comment: why not: `imageName = "hangman"+error+".jpg";` ? of course you'll have to change the next lines to: `if(!"hangman0.jpg".equals(imageName))...`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting error to `0` before you do your checks.

Remove this line:

```
error =0;
```

Comment: even when I remove it the image remains the same

Comment: @user1614977 try adding a call to `repaint()` after you change the image

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (as in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151399/hangman-picture-isnt-changing)).

Comment: @user1614977 after you do `error++`, are you actually calling the code that you posted above to change the picture?

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it's unclear if you add the `JLabel` `image` to the parent container.

Recreating the `JLabel` is unnecessary.

Simply create a single instance and call `image.setIcon(...);`